# Storm supervisor displaying message "kill: sending signal to 23543 failed: No such process"

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I started storm cluster and all one nimbus and two supervisors started fine and I could view them fine on "Storm UI"  then I deployed example topology "storm-opentsdb-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",

it is successfully deployed on the cluster but after few minutes supervisor console displays message and no data is inserted in Opentsdb.

```
kill: sending signal to 23543 failed: No such process
kill: sending signal to 23615 failed: No such process
kill: sending signal to 23612 failed: No such process
kill: sending signal to 23706 failed: No such process
kill: sending signal to 23776 failed: No such process.
```

The same topology run perfectly fine in Local Cluster mode and inserts data in OpenTSDB.

To resolve this issue I killed the topology, killed the nimbus and supervisor nodes. I manually deleted files under 
**"storm.local.dir: "/tmp/storm-data""** and also deleted the files in zookeeper znode /storm.

Again started the cluster and deployed the same topology but got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by changing the storm.yaml property storm.messaging.transport to org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Context .